VSCode Data Wrangler view dataframes from code tab
I'm currently learning pandas and use VSCode as IDE. It has great extension to view dataframes called Data Wrangler.
In order to view dataframe you have click on 'View in Data Wrangler' button from Jupyter Variables tab.
Before learning pandas I wrote code on R in RStudio and it has function to view objects straight from the code: you just need to put your cursor on dataframe definition in your code, press ctrl + left mouse button and it opened dataframe in new tab.
Does Data Wrangler have an option to view dataframes not from Jupyter Variables tab, but straight from the code, where dataframe is defined (like in RStudio)?
